# Update dynamically dynamoDB using update_item

Tags: python-3.x, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, dynamodb-queries

```
        UpdateExpression="set #app[idx].#st = :stVal",
```

I have stored the value of idx as variable. But DynamoDB throws error saying invalid 'idx'.

How do I use the value stored in idx in UpdateExpression.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to this would be to using format strings and then replace.

```
    updateExp = "set #app[{}].#st = :stVal".format(idx)
```